# Law of tangents with an angle bisector without knowing angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

"In $\triangle ABC$, let D be a point on BC such that AD bisects $\angle A$. If AD=6, BD=4, and DC=3, then find AB"

This problem is from the Mu Alpha Theta 1991 contest, it appears in volume 2 of AoPS and involves law of tangents. I have tried looking the possible cases where I can use law of tangents, but I don´t see clear the path to solve the problem. So I hope you can give me a hint to be able to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok guys, I thank you for your help. But I would like to know how the solution would be using the law of tangents which is the topic I am studying now.

Comment: The law of tangents
is a strange choice in this case, since 
"[the law of tangents or tangent rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents), 
can be used to find a side or an angle 
when you know two sides and an angle 
or two angles and a side.", which is not what is given in the question.

Comment: I'm asking for that way to solve it because it appears in the tangent law section as an intermediate level problem in https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Law_of_Tangents . However, if I had to choose a solution to the problem, I would go with the one involving Stewart's theorem, which I found very beautiful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Given $a_1=|BD|=4$, $a_2=|DC|=3$
and $d=|AD|=6$, let $|AC|=b$ and $|AB|=c$.

By the [Angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)
for $\angle CAB$ we can express $c$ in terms of $b$:
\begin{align}
c &= \frac{a_1}{a_2}\cdot b
,
\end{align}

and by the
[Stewart’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)
we have one more equation in terms of $b$ and $c$:

\begin{align}
a_1 b^2+a_2 c^2&=(a_1+a_2)(d^2+a_1a_2)
,
\end{align}
so we can find $b^2$ as

\begin{align}
b^2 &= \frac{a_2}{a_1}\cdot(d^2+a_1a_2)
=36
,
\end{align}
hence,
\begin{align}
b&=6
,\quad
\text{and }\quad
c=8
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Geometric solution:
[image]

Conidering figure we have:

$AK=AD+DK=6-DK$

$AH=AD-DH=6-DH$

In triangle CC'E: $CD=DE\Rightarrow BE=4-3=1$

Triangles BC'E and BAD are similar and we have:

$\frac{BE}{BD}=\frac {C'E}{AD}\Rightarrow C'D=\frac 64=\frac 32$

$\frac{DH}{C'D}=\frac 36=\frac 12\Rightarrow DH=\frac12 C'D=\frac34$

Triangles DHC and DKB are similar so:

$DH=\frac43 DH \Rightarrow DK=1$

In right angle triangle ABK we have:

$AK=AD+DK=6+1=7$

$BK^2=4^2-1^2=15$

$AB=\sqrt{BK^2+AK^2=15+7^2=64}=8$

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote AB=c , BC=a and AC=b

Therefore , BC=BD+CD=7

*a=7*

Now , as AD is the angle bisector ,

Therefore , AB/AC = BD/CD ,or

c/b = 4/3 = k(say)

Therefore , *c=4k , b=3k*

Now , the length of angle bisector AD is given by

**AD=(2bc/(b+c))cos(A/2)**

Plugging in AD=6 , b=3k and c=4k , we get the value of cos(A/2) as

**cos(A/2)=7/4k**

Now , calculating value of cos(A)

cos(A)= 2cos²(A/2)-1

Therefore ,
**cos(A)=(49-8k²)/8k²**

Now , using cosine rule ,which states that ,

cos(A)= (b²+c²-a²)/2bc

Plugging in values

49-8k²/8k² = {(4k)² + (3k)²- a²}/2(4k)(3k)

=>49(3)-24k²=25k²-49

49(4)=49k², therefore , k²=4

Therefore , ***k=2*** (neglecting negative value )

Therefore , ***AB=4k=4(2)=8***

Comment: How can $\triangle ABD$ have  side lengths of $6,4$ and $56$?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that !!! @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Did a  silly calculation mistake , corrected it ..@DanielWainfleet

Comment: Please post in MathJax.